# How to setup VIM with python3 and YouCompleteMe in virtualenv

Tags: vim, python3

I would like to develop python3 with VIM on my Ubuntu 16.04. I setup my .vimrc mostly according to [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/) and installed the package YouCompleteMe (YCM) with Vundle.

When YCM starts I get the following error message:

```
Error: Required vim compiled with +python
E117: Unknown function: pythoncomplete#Complete
```

`vim --version` shows me that I have a VIM with with `+python3` and `-python`.

Since I really want to develop python3 and VIM on Ubuntu 16.04 comes with `+python3` by default I do not want to install VIM with python 2.

In the [YouCompleteMe documentation](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) it says that you can have VIM with python 2 or python 3 support, so I guess there must be a way.
Also in the YouCompleteMe development forums I can see that in the beginning of 2016 python 3 support was added.

So, how can I get it to work?

Later on I would like to use it in a virtualenv, but currently the error messages are the same with and without virtualenv.

Comment: i think you should install `vim-nox` or `vim-nox-py2` package. edit: sorry i misunderstood your question

Comment: Unless you want to write vimscripts in Python 3, there's no problem in installing Vim with Python2 support, even if you're a Python3 dev.

Comment: have you run `install.py` from YouCompleteMe plugin folder?

Comment: @TamadoSitohang No, I have not. What does it do exactly? I came across it before but I didn't run it because I installed YCM with Vundle. Will it interfere with Vundle somehow?

Comment: @muru What is the point of Vim with Python3 then? Which disadvantage do I have running Vim with Python2?

Comment: The point is that some people like writing plugins for Vim in Python 3. The disadvantage of Vim+python2 is that if you come across a plugin supporting only Vim+python3, you won't be able to run it (most popular plugins are in Python2 only or support both, so it shouldn't matter).

Comment: After running install.py it started working. Nevertheless I still find it strange that I have to run an install script after installing with a package manager (pip).